# Difficult to start a triple integral

Tags: definite-integrals

I have to calculate the integrale of $f$ on $T$.

I think it is a triple integrale, but I didn't manage to solve it.

$$
f(x,y,z)=\frac{1}{1+x+y+z}
$$
$$
T=\{(x, y, z)\in{(\mathbb R^+)^3}:||(x, y, z)||_1\le{1}\}
$$
With
$$
T=\{(x, y, z)\in{(\mathbb R^+)^3}:0\le{x}\le{1},0\le{y}\le{1-x}, 0\le{z}\le{1-x-y}\}
$$

I try to integrate first by $z$, then $y$, then $x$, is it good way ? I have to use spherical coordinate or not ? I have find this integral to solve :
$$
\int\limits_{0}^{1} \int\limits_{0}^{1-x} \int\limits_{0}^{1-x-y} f(x,y,z)\mathrm dz\mathrm dy\mathrm dx
$$

Comment: How about this change of variables: $(u,v,w)=(x,x+y,x+y+z)$?

Comment: My change of variables gives
$$\int_0^1\int_0^w\int_0^v\frac{du\,dv\,dw}{1+w}.$$